# What is the detailed story of Rishi Jabali turning cow meat into onions?

Tags: scripture, rishi, food, reference-request, cows

In the book "*Accounts of the Writings, Religions and Manners of the Hindoos*" by William Ward published in 1811 there is a section on extraordinary deeds by various high-souled Rishis. (Pages 312 to 314). All except one are well-known. That one is Jabali/Javalee turning stolen cow meat meant for sacrifice to onions in order to escape detection.

[image]

Can someone please help find the reference to the section in the scriptures that has this incident?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the anecdote of Jabali referred to here is true. Every single word of the page of which you provided screenshot of, is laced with Christian chauvinism prevalent among the Europeans in those days.

Comment: That maybe true. But the underlying stories are there in scriptures. Just cant find the Jabali one

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as opinion based ? If thats the case then even questions like these ought to be closed
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13905/what-is-the-story-of-jadbharat

Comment: This is a comment and there is no answer. I tried to look for this story and found no confirming evidence. This I think a best information...https://www.hindudevotionalblog.com/2020/01/jaabaali-maharshi-jabali-rishi-hindu.html. William Ward, I think was inventing his own ways to undermine Hindus.